Parameter to select data displayed on map in tableau
I'm using a public dataset (https://www.dol.gov/agencies/wcb/ctcocpiccccs/featured-childcare)
I'm currently trying to create a dashboard that display several variables geographically using the county name and demographic data. I was hoping to do this with a drop down. I found a method here recommended by Tableau (https://jimdehner.com/2022/07/05/parameters-how-tos/) but I can't figure out what to do now that I created the parameter and the calculated value with the "case when" statement. Let me know if you need any more details.
